# Alguien me puede ayudar mejorar esta consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Esta consulta tarda 15 a 20 min en ejecutarse sobre 10 mil registros hay forma de hacerla mas eficiente? o simplemente ya no se puede?

```
SELECT DISTINCT SALIDAS.NO_REMESA, 
       SALIDAS.NUMERO_DE_PEDIDO, 
       SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO AS "ESCANEO_SALIDA", 
       EMPACADORES.ID_DE_PEDIDO, EMPACADORES.ID_DE_REMESA,
       EMPACADORES.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO AS "ESCANEO_EMPACADORES"
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NO_REMESA, 
                    NUMERO_DE_PEDIDO, 
                    FECHA_DE_ESCANEO 
                    FROM SALIDAS 
                    WHERE NO_REMESA >= '171719'
       ) AS SALIDAS
       LEFT JOIN EMPACADORES 
            ON SALIDAS.NO_REMESA = EMPACADORES.ID_DE_REMESA 
            AND SALIDAS.NUMERO_DE_PEDIDO = EMPACADORES.ID_DE_PEDIDO
       WHERE SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO != EMPACADORES.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO 
             OR (EMPACADORES.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO IS NULL
                 AND SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO IS NOT NULL) 
             OR (EMPACADORES.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO IS NOT NULL 
                 AND SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO IS NULL);
```

estas son las tablas con las que se esta trabajando...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es la creacion de la tabla salidas conforme el codigo solcitado

```
'salidas', 'CREATE TABLE `salidas` (\n  `NO_REMESA` double DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `FECHA_DE_REMESA` date DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `MENSAJERIA` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `NUMERO_DE_PEDIDO` double DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `ESTATUS_DEL_PROD_EN_LA_REMESA` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `SKU` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `DESCRIPCION` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `FECHA_DE_ESCANEO` date DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `SKU Qty` double DEFAULT NULL\n)
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci'
```

esta es la creacion de la tabla empacadores conforme el codigo solicitado

```
'empacadores', 'CREATE TABLE `empacadores` (\n  `ID_DE_PEDIDO` double DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `FECHA_DE_ESCANEO` date DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `HORA_DE_ESCANEO` time DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `ID_DE_USUARIO` double DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `NOMBRE_DE_USUARIO` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `ID_DE_REMESA` double DEFAULT NULL,
\n  `MENSAJERIA` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL\n)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci'
```

Comment: Deberías añadir la estructura de las tablas que hay en la consulta para poder hacer las pruebas necesarias para ver cual puede ser el problema o como mejorar la estructura o la consulta.

Comment: listo ya puse las tablas que se usan para la consulta...

Comment: @Gustavo que version de mysql usas? pasame un export de la estructura de esas tablas

Comment: la versión es la 8.0.16 de mysql y a que te refieres con un export? necesitas los datos de las tablas??? eso lo puedo subir aqui???

Comment: datos no necesito en principio, es la estructura de esas dos tablas en sql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: estas tablas tienen indices? a simple vista es dificil decirte que se puede hacer sin mucha mas informacion.. que dice el explain plan?

Comment: y el where no tiene sentido.. si SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO != EMPACADORES.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO , entonces si uno es null (como preguntas abajo), el otro no es null por defecto.. o no lo tomaria.. si fueran los dos null, ya lo bloqueo la primera clausula.. en realidad se come a todas als de abajo, pero eso no puede hacerla lenta.. el problema es probable que sea tu distinct alla adentro..

Comment: @gbianchi no no puedo poner incides porque seria una relacion de muchos a muchos un pedido puede estar en muchas remesas y una remesa puede tener muchos pedidos

Comment: y que tienen que ver los indices con eso?

Comment: que tengo muchos datos repetidos por los id donde podria poner un indice

Comment: @Gustavo pasame lo que te he dicho y miro si se puede hacer algo

Comment: @KeTeMeTo en eso estoy pero no se como pegarlo aqui jajajaja se ve horrible pero ahi va

Comment: 'salidas', 'CREATE TABLE `salidas` ( `NO_REMESA` double DEFAULT NULL,
`FECHA_DE_REMESA` date DEFAULT NULL,
`MENSAJERIA` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`NUMERO_DE_PEDIDO` double DEFAULT NULL,
`ESTATUS_DEL_PROD_EN_LA_REMESA` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`SKU` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`DESCRIPCION` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`FECHA_DE_ESCANEO` date DEFAULT NULL,
`SKU Qty` double DEFAULT NULL\n)
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: 'empacadores', 'CREATE TABLE `empacadores` (\n  `ID_DE_PEDIDO` double DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `FECHA_DE_ESCANEO` date DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `HORA_DE_ESCANEO` time DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `ID_DE_USUARIO` double DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `NOMBRE_DE_USUARIO` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `ID_DE_REMESA` double DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `MENSAJERIA` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL\n)
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci'

Comment: @Gustavo no lo pongas por aqui, edita la pregunta y lo pegas como codigo en la pregunta

Comment: ya lo intente y no me deja dice que como es codigo tengo que dar mas documentacion aunque ya modifique todo jajajaja lo siento sigo sin aprender a usar esta herramienta!!!

Comment: Bueno trankilo ahora te edito yo y lo pongo bien no te preocupes

Comment: Y que tiene que ver la repeticion de datos con los indices?

Comment: Y de paso agreguen el explain plan...

Comment: tienes razon @gbianchi ya me puse a leer sobre los indices y no tiene nada que ver mas bien lo estaba confundiendo con las llaves primarias pero entonces ninguna de mis tablas tiene indices

Comment: O sea, que ademas de que el distinct tiene que recorrer toda la tabla para armarse, en cada join tiene que recorrerla devuelta para joinear (o por lo menos leerla toda y ordenarla) y para hacer el where tambien hace full scan...

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo hay que agregar indices

```
ALTER TABLE `EMPACADORES` ADD INDEX `empacadores_idx_escaneo` (`FECHA_DE_ESCANEO`);
ALTER TABLE `SALIDAS` ADD INDEX `salidas_idx_remesa` (`NO_REMESA`);
```

Esta es la consulta

```
SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        ((SELECT
            DISTINCT SALIDAS.NO_REMESA,
            SALIDAS.NUMERO_DE_PEDIDO,
            SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO AS 'ESCANEO_SALIDA',
            EMPACADORES.ID_DE_PEDIDO,
            EMPACADORES.ID_DE_REMESA,
            EMPACADORES.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO AS 'ESCANEO_EMPACADORES' 
        FROM
            (SELECT
                DISTINCT SALIDAS.NO_REMESA,
                SALIDAS.NUMERO_DE_PEDIDO,
                SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO 
            FROM
                SALIDAS 
            WHERE
                SALIDAS.NO_REMESA >= '171719') AS SALIDAS 
        INNER JOIN
            EMPACADORES 
                ON SALIDAS.NO_REMESA = EMPACADORES.ID_DE_REMESA 
                AND SALIDAS.NUMERO_DE_PEDIDO = EMPACADORES.ID_DE_PEDIDO 
        WHERE
            (
                EMPACADORES.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO IS NOT NULL 
                AND SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO IS NULL
            )
        ) 
    UNION
    DISTINCT (SELECT
        DISTINCT SALIDAS.NO_REMESA,
        SALIDAS.NUMERO_DE_PEDIDO,
        SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO AS 'ESCANEO_SALIDA',
        EMPACADORES.ID_DE_PEDIDO,
        EMPACADORES.ID_DE_REMESA,
        EMPACADORES.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO AS 'ESCANEO_EMPACADORES' 
    FROM
        (SELECT
            DISTINCT SALIDAS.NO_REMESA,
            SALIDAS.NUMERO_DE_PEDIDO,
            SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO 
        FROM
            SALIDAS 
        WHERE
            SALIDAS.NO_REMESA >= '171719') AS SALIDAS 
    LEFT JOIN
        EMPACADORES 
            ON SALIDAS.NO_REMESA = EMPACADORES.ID_DE_REMESA 
            AND SALIDAS.NUMERO_DE_PEDIDO = EMPACADORES.ID_DE_PEDIDO 
    WHERE
        SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO != EMPACADORES.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO 
        OR (EMPACADORES.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO IS NULL 
        AND SALIDAS.FECHA_DE_ESCANEO IS NOT NULL))
) AS union1
```

Si no eliminas los duplicados, tambien usaria `UNION ALL` en vez de `UNION`

Comment: @Gustavo espero te sirva, ahora me comentas

Comment: Porque un union? como puede ser mas rapido esta consulta que la anterior, con solo agregar los indices?

Comment: @KeTeMeTo pues la voy a probar me llama la atencion el union ya que casi nunca lo ocupo pero deja me documento un poco mas sobre eso muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Las uniones son mas rapidas que las condiciones, los inner joins son mas rapidos que los left joins

Comment: @KeTeMeTo alguna fuente donde se pueda corroborar lo que mencionas?

Comment: @Aprendiz realizando una consulta y otra con los mismos registros y viendo el tiempo de la ejecucion